For every upper triangular matrix $A$ there exists an upper triangular matrix $B$ such that $AB$ is idempotent
Suppose $A=\begin{pmatrix}
    a_{11} &a_{12}& \cdots & a_{1n} \\ 
    0 & a_{22}&\cdots &a_{2n} \\ 
.&.&\cdots&.\\
0&0&\cdots&a_{nn}\end{pmatrix}$ is an upper triangular matrix over a ring. Is it always true that there exists a nonzero upper triangular matrix $B$ such that $AB$ is an idempotent matrix.
I can think of a matrix like
$B=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 &0& \cdots & 0 \\ 
    0 & 0&\cdots &0 \\ 
.&.&\cdots&.\\
0&0&\cdots&0\end{pmatrix}$ then $AB=\begin{pmatrix}
    a_{11} &0& \cdots & 0 \\ 
    0 & 0&\cdots &0 \\ 
.&.&\cdots&.\\
0&0&\cdots&0\end{pmatrix}$. So $a_{11}$ must be idempotent which is not necessary always? Any other suggestions?

Hint: For every upper triangular matrix there is an upper triangular matrix such that their product is nilpotent.

I am taking matrix over a ring, so inverse may not exists

First thought is that you can always multiply on a unit on the right (a diagonal matrix even) so that $A$ has just $0$'s and $1$'s on the diagonal.  Then you have reached a form where $A=e+n$ where $e$ is idempotent and $n$ is nilpotent.  For a nonzero nilpotent your proposition holds, because there'll be $n'\neq 0$ such that $nn'=0$.  But I haven't seen the way forward if $en'$ happens to be nonzero.  There will be $n"$ such that $en'n"=0$, but it's not clear that $n'n"\neq 0$ has to happen.

Let the ring be $k[t]$, polynomials over a field $k$.
Let $A$ be the upper triangular matrix $\begin{pmatrix}t&t\\0&t\end{pmatrix}$. Or I could even take the $1\times1$ matrix $\begin{pmatrix}t\end{pmatrix}$ or the diagonal matrix $\begin{pmatrix}t&0\\0&t\end{pmatrix}$ if it's not cheating to use a $1\times1$ or diagonal matrix.
Since $A=tA'$ for an invertible matrix $A'$, if $B$ is a nonzero matrix, then $AB$ is a nonzero matrix whose entries are all divisible by $t$. If $t^n$ is the largest power of $t$ that divides all entries of $AB$, then $t^{2n}$ divides all entries of $(AB)^2$, and so $AB\neq (AB)^2$, and so $AB$ cannot be idempotent.
